# How to make PyCharm autocomplete VueJS code in *.html (django template)

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

We use `VueJS` inside `Django` templates. Every template has it's own VueJS app.

base.html

```
<div id="vue">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</div> ...
```

page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
...
<div v-if="..."..</div>
{% endblock %}
<script>
new Vue({...
</script>
```

The problem is that `PyCharm` doesn't recognize that we use `Vue` so it doesn't highlight or autocomplete things like `v-if` etc...

In`*.vue` files, everything works correctly.

Is there a way to inject the language to the file or another way to tell PyCharm that we use Vue?

**EDIT**

When I go to **Editor -> File Types -> Vue.js Template**, there is only `*.vue` pattern. So I try to add `*.html` but `PyCharm` warns me `This wildcard is already registered by HTML filetype Reassign wildcard?`

Comment: Vue.js in Django templates is not supported; it should be either HTML with `<script src="path/to/vue.js"></script>` link or a single file component defined in `.vue` file (HTML files + vue.js installed with `npm` also work).